# wordpress superfish dropdown menu

Tags: menus, navigation

I am learning how to integrate superfish drop down menus in wordpress and i am following this tutorial http://kav.in/wordpress-superfish-dropdown-menu

I am using this theme with superfish integrated http://kav.in/blog/wp-content/uploads/dload/axtra_with_superfish.zip

Has anyone else successfully been able to make the menus show?.

Comment: in most cases the problem is a double jquery... can you paste the header code between <head> & </head> - not the output but the code as it is in the header.php file ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it.I had to add menus under the appearance menu and worked perfectly.

Comment: Glad you have to worked out..